# Git checkout without args

Tags: bash, git

In the git docs it says

> git checkout < branch>
>
> You could omit < branch>, in which case the
>   command degenerates to "check out the current branch", which is a
>   glorified no-op with rather expensive side-effects to show only the
>   tracking information, if exists, for the current branch.

I would like to change this default behavior so that without an argument it checks out master instead of the current branch.

*Alternative solution if not possible*

I currently have the following in my bash profile:

```
alias gco='git checkout'
__git_complete gco _git_checkout
```

How can I change this to be a function such that without an argument it checks out master, and otherwise uses the above behavior like so...

```
gco()
{
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
    git checkout master
else
    # autocomplete as above and alias to just git checkout?
fi
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function gco(){
    if [ -z "$1" ]; then
        git checkout master
    else
        git checkout "$1"
    fi
}
```

Check out [Bash Comparison Operators](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html) and [Functions](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/functions.html).

---

As mentioned in the comments, an advanced alternative involves [Bash Parameter Substitution](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html) and [Internal Variables](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#APPREF).

```
gco() { git checkout "${@-master}";
```

Whichever you chose, be sure to understand it so that you can explain it to others and make changes as needed.

Comment: or just `gco() { git checkout "${@-master}"; }`.

Comment: Also, `gco() { (($# == 0)) && set master; git checkout "$@"; }`